# Changing the number of digits in JMP bar chart label

Tags: sas-jmp

In JMP bar chart, the label has too many digits, how can I change it to less?
[image]

Comment: Question about programming are better suited for stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you go back to the data table. Right click on the columns that are in the graph. Go to Column properties. Change the width from 10 to whatever specified length you want.

So for example if you change the column width to 3. Column WHA2F14 will read 3.1 in the bar chart.

Note: This method works only for continuous(interval) variables.